# Кнопки шаринга для соц.сетей Angular 6

Tags: angular, соцсети

Может есть какие-то готовые компоненты которые могут позволить делать репост записей в соц. сети для Angular 6? Посоветуйте кто чем пользуется и какие плюсы и минусы у существующих готовых компонентов. Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таких компонентов не пруд пруди, но есть, который постоянно поддерживается `ngx-sharebuttons` https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-sharebuttons, очень прост в установке и использовании:

```
yarn add @ngx-share/{core,button}
```

Импортируем модуль:

```
// app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { ShareButtonModule } from '@ngx-share/button';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ShareButtonModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [...],
    bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Импортируем нужные нам стили:

```
@import '~@ngx-share/button/styles/share-buttons';
@import '~@ngx-share/button/styles/themes/default/default-theme';
```

Теперь можем использовать компонент `share-button` в нашем приложении:

```
<share-button button="facebook"></share-button>
```

`button` это `binding`, принимает строкой провайдер для шаринга (`facebook | linkedin | telegram | vk`). При клике на кнопку открывается popup для шаринга, вы можете указать свой через `binding` `url`

```
<share-button button="facebook" url="https://facebook.com?share=BLAH_BLAH"></share-button>
```

Не забываем про иконки:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
yarn add @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
yarn add @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

К сожалению, в `ngx-sharebuttons V6` для `Angular 6+` нужно вручную импортировать их в `polyfills.ts`:

```
import { library, IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

import { faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faFacebookF';
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg- icons/faTwitter';
import { faRedditAlien } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faRedditAlien';
import { faLinkedinIn } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faLinkedinIn';
import { faGooglePlusG } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faGooglePlusG';
import { faTumblr } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faTumblr';
import { faPinterestP } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faPinterestP';
import { faWhatsapp } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faWhatsapp';
import { faVk } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faVk';
import { faFacebookMessenger } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faFacebookMessenger';
import { faTelegramPlane } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faTelegramPlane';

const icons: IconDefinition[] = [
    faFacebookF,
    faTwitter,
    faLinkedinIn,
    faGooglePlusG,
    faPinterestP,
    faRedditAlien,
    faTumblr,
    faWhatsapp,
    faVk,
    faFacebookMessenger,
    faTelegramPlane,
    ......
];

library.add(...icons);
```

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю что за оно и как работает.

Comment: Спасибо, отличные кнопки, жаль что OK нету)